# How to remove a crashing applet from Gnome Panel?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I tried to add an applet to my gnome panel in Ubuntu Hardy 8.04 but the applet is crashing for a reason that I can't fix.

Since it crashes immediately, I can't remove it in the normal way (right click and remove) and therefore it tries to load again everytime I restart.  I assume there's a configuration file somewhere that specifies the applets but I haven't found it yet.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is even a configuration tool for this. Open up a terminal, and type gconf-editor.

[image]

This will bring up a window with a tree view on the left, first of all, expand the node "apps", scroll down to panel, expand that one as well, in here you will see a node called applets, containing all applets on your desktop, you can configure these and delete these I believe.

[image]

I hope this will help you further

PS: Ubuntu 9.10 is pretty stable here, maybe time for an update soon :D?

Comment: I slept thru Intrepid and Jaunty and Karmic have a major hardware regression on my laptop so I'm quite happy with a functional, but older system.  Maybe the next LTS will work.

Comment: Ah same here, my grub takes like 15 seconds too long and afcours ATI graphic card. I thought about going back to 9.04 until 9.10 had a few more updates, but well, I like ext4 and haven't had any other problems yet so, can't wait for the 10.04 though!; They kind of fixed my grub problem, for a bit.